# C# checking for binary reader end of file

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, binaryreader

I was searching for a way to check whether I've reached the end of a file for my binary reader and one suggestion was to use PeekChar as such

```
while (inFile.PeekChar() > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

However, it looks like I've run into an issue

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The output char buffer is too sma
ll to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'Syste
m.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.
Parameter name: chars
   at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow()
   at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow(DecoderNLS decoder, Boolean nothin
gDecoded)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* char
s, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars,
 Int32 charCount, Boolean flush)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteC
ount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteC
ount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.InternalReadOneChar()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.PeekChar()
```

So maybe PeekChar isn't the best way to do it, and I don't think it should even be used that way because I'm checking the current position of my reader and not really what the next character is supposed to be.

Comment: Use StreamReader (char stream) to read the  Text file. I'd suggest BinaryReader.ReadBytes(nBytes_to_be_read) if you want to read a file.

Comment: Depending on your specific code and whether the file access is shared, you may also be able to cache the stream's .Length property to a local variable, which will optimize and improve the performance even more.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is a more accurate way to check for EOF when working with binary data. It avoids all of the encoding issues that come with the `PeekChar` approach and does exactly what is needed: to check whether the position of the reader is at the end of the file or not.

```
while (inFile.BaseStream.Position != inFile.BaseStream.Length)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `Position` and `Length` are properties, not methods, of the `Stream` class.  Unless you've defined extension methods with those same names, the method call syntax won't compile.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I wrote them as methods before.

Comment: This only works if the underlying Stream supports seeking.

Comment: @Paul So does `PeekChar`, so that's not really a difference :)

Comment: @Paul unless I'm mistaken the ability to seek is not the same as the ability to read length and position of a stream. Though, usually a fixed length stream will be seekable.

Comment: Depending the underlying stream, calling `BaseStream.Length` might be really slow. `FileStream` for eg, will call `Win32.GetFileSize()` each time. If you know length is not going to change, you might want to cache it first (eg : in a local var)

Answer (score 8):

I suggest very similar to @MxLDevs, but with a '<' operator rather than a '!=' operator. As it is possible to set Position to anything you want (within long confines), this will stop any attempts to access an invalid file Position by the loop.

```
while (inFile.BaseStream.Position < inFile.BaseStream.Length)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrapping it into a [Custom Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb311042.aspx) that'll extend the *BinaryReader* class by adding the missing EOF method.

```
public static class StreamEOF {

    public static bool EOF( this BinaryReader binaryReader ) {
        var bs = binaryReader.BaseStream;
        return ( bs.Position == bs.Length);
    }
}
```

So now you can just write:

```
while (!infile.EOF()) {
   // Read....
}
```

:)
... assuming you have created **infile** somewhere like this:

```
var infile= new BinaryReader();
```

Note: [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb383973.aspx) is implicit typing.
Happy to found it - it's other puzzle piece for well styled code in C#. :D

Comment: wrong, very wrong. should be         return ( bs.Position == bs.Length); and !infile.EOF()

Answer (score 3):

**This work for me:**

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName,   
FileMode.Open))) {
            //int pos = 0;
            //int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;
            while (br.BaseStream.Position != br.BaseStream.Length) {
                string nume = br.ReadString ();
                string prenume = br.ReadString ();
                Persoana p = new Persoana (nume, prenume);
                myArrayList.Add (p);
                Console.WriteLine ("ADAUGAT XXX: "+ p.ToString());
                //pos++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll add my suggestion: if you don't need the "encoding" part of the BinaryReader (so you don't use the various ReadChar/ReadChars/ReadString) then you can use an encoder that won't ever throw and that is always one-byte-per-char. `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` is perfect for this. You pass it as a parameter of the `BinaryReader` constructor. The iso-8859-1 encoding is a one-byte-per-character encoding that maps 1:1 all the first 256 characters of Unicode (so the `byte` 254 is the `char` 254 for example)

Comment: One of the comments addressed an issue with streams that don't support seeking wouldn't support checking the length of the stream directly. I suppose this may resolve that issue under such circumstances.

Comment: @MxyL No, it won't solve *that* problem. The `PeekChar()` does a `Read()` and then uses the `Position` to rollback the `Read()`.

Comment: For clarity, what would be the suggested approach to checking the end of the file with a specific encoding?