# how to make a if statement which checkes if variable offset is equal to end of base stream?

Tags: c#

what I wanted to make is a if statement which checks if the variable which has a offset in it is equal to the base stream length and if it is, it will break.

here is what I have:

```
//open.FileName is Test.txt which doesn't have the number 123 (aka "7B")
        user_input = "123";
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName));
        for (int i = 0; i <= br.BaseStream.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == br.BaseStream.Length) //for some reason this doesn't work. why?
            {
                br.Close();
                operation_Info.Text = operation_Fail;
                break;
            }
            br.BaseStream.Position = i;
            string Locate = br.ReadInt32().ToString();
            if (Locate == user_input)
            {
                br.Close();
                operation_Info.Text = operation_Success;
                break;
            }
         }
```

For some reason it ignores the `if` and tries to check for 123 again but gives the error `System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'` sins its already at the end of the file. why doesnt the `if` work?

Comment: Take a look at how the condition is coded in the accepted answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942848/c-sharp-checking-for-binary-reader-end-of-file

Comment: oh. Thanks for linking me that @DavidTansey :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- #SOReadyToHelp

Answer (score 1):

Change your 'if' statement to:

```
if (i == br.BaseStream.Length - 3)
```

The reason it is failing is because you attempt to read 4 bytes with the ReadInt32() method when you are less than 4 bytes from the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is unnecessary.  You should just change your loop variable so that it only goes to `br.BaseStream.Length - 3` instead.

Also, if your text file has the actual string "123" then using `ReadInt32` will not work like you think it will.  The string "123" is represented by the bytes `0x31 0x32 0x33`.  Depending on what character appears before it or after it will affect the value that `ReadInt32` returns.

For example, if the string has a space before it, then the bytes will be 0x20313233 and the value returned by `ReadInt32` will be 858927392 and if there is a space *after* the 123, the bytes will be 0x31323320 and the returned value will be 540226097.

If you're searching for the numeric value of 123, then the bytes will be 0x7B000000 in the file.  The `BinaryReader` will read them using Big Endian order (assuming Windows).

You should research Big Endian, Little Endian, and how strings and numbers are represented in binary in a file.