# How to read whole binary file (not only the first variables) including string, long and int

Tags: c#, binary, system.io.file, binaryreader

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (var bw1 = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    bw1.Write(jmeno);
    bw1.Write(date);
    bw1.Write(rodnecislo);
    bw1.Write(sarze);
}

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var br1 = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    string readname = br1.ReadString();
    int readdate = br1.ReadInt32();
    long readcislo = br1.ReadInt64();
    long readsarze = br1.ReadInt64();
    Console.WriteLine(readname);
    Console.WriteLine(readdate);
    Console.WriteLine(readcislo);
    Console.WriteLine(readsarze);
}
```

This is how the BinaryWriter looks like. I don't know how to make the console write this whole binary file.

Comment: The caption says "read", the code says "write"??

Comment: This is the Binary writer. It works fine, but I want to display this binary file via console writeline

Comment: Seems to me that you already gave the answer yourself...

Comment: Still don't get your problem, You have the code to write and to read. What exactly is missing or does not work?

Comment: @KlausGütter Right now it only reads the first string, int and long. But when I append something new, it doesnt display in console. So I would like to fix it, but I dont know how

Comment: Have you thought about reading the four variables in a loop until the end of the file is reached?

Comment: @KlausGütter I have. But I dont know how to do it. I am new in this stuff. Or I can use method ReadAllBytes, but the enconding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OK, then here is how to do it:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var br1 = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    while (br1.BaseStream.Position != br1.BaseStream.Length)
    {
        string readname = br1.ReadString();
        int readdate = br1.ReadInt32();
        long readcislo = br1.ReadInt64();
        long readsarze = br1.ReadInt64();
        Console.WriteLine(readname);
        Console.WriteLine(readdate);
        Console.WriteLine(readcislo);
        Console.WriteLine(readsarze);
    }
}
```

For an explanation of the while condition see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942848/c-sharp-checking-for-binary-reader-end-of-file)